# Hover nested vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a nested & re-used vue component. I am trying to use v-show to display part of the component (icons) when its outer parent is hovered. To achieve this I am passing the parent and child index as props but my parent element is returning true for v-show when the child element is hovered. What can I do to remedy this?

```
<div v-for="course, index in courses">

  <!-- hover me -->
  <div class="header" @mouseover="setShowIndex(index)" @mouseout="resetShowIndex">

  <!-- part of this component should v-show when its parent is hovered -->
  <MyCustomComponent
     type="course"
     :showCourseIndex="showCourseIndex"
  />

  <!-- items.lessons can be hovered too, but the parent should not v-show when this is hovered -->
  <div 
    v-for="lesson, i in course.lessons"
    @mouseover="setShowIndex(index, i)" 
    @mouseout="resetShowIndex"
  >
    <MyCustomComponent
       type="lesson"
       :showCourseIndex="showCourseIndex"
       :showLessonIndex="showLessonIndex"
    />
  </div>
</div


/** 
 * update indexes to pass as props
 */
setShowIndex(index, i) {
  if (i !== undefined) {
      this.showLessonIndex = i;
  }
  this.showCourseIndex = index;
},

resetShowIndex() {
  this.showCourseIndex = null;
  this.showLessonIndex = null;
}
```

```
// MyCustomComponent

<div>
  <!-- ... more -->
  <div v-show="shouldShowIndex">
    <p>Show me</p>
  </div>
  <!-- ... more -->
</div>


computed: {

    shouldShowIndex() {

      if ( this.type == 'lesson'
        && this.showModuleIndex == this.moduleIndex 
        && this.showLessonIndex == this.lessonIndex ) {

        return true;

      } else if (this.type == 'course' && this.showModuleIndex == this.moduleIndex ) {

        return true; // problem here, this is returning True when a lesson is hovered

      }

      return false;
    },

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the header should display it's its icon if its hovered, and the lessons should display their icon if hovered, but not trigger the header.

```
setShowIndex(index, i) {
  if (i !== undefined) {
      this.showLessonIndex = i;
  } else {
      this.showCourseIndex = index;
  }
},
```

Do you just need an else there?

Comment: thanks - the problem with this is we need the lesson to display for the correct index of its parent course, so we need the course index & lesson index. Will throw a fiddle together later

Comment: `else if (this.type == 'course' && this.showModuleIndex == this.moduleIndex && this.showLessonIndex  == null)`